# How to plot the the following function in Maple 12?

Tags: maple

How to plot     $\quad f(t) =
\begin{cases}
a,  & \text{if $t=0$ } \\
e^{-b.t}, & \text{if $t>0$}  \\
0, & \text{if $t<0$}
\end{cases}
$ using maple 12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is animate the plot for one of the parameters, fixing the other one. The interesting parameter is of course $b$ since $a$ is just a single value at $x=0$. The following command animates the function for $b$ between $0$ and $5$ and gives a general idea of how the function behave when $b$ gains in magnitude.

> f:=t->piecewise(t=0,a,t<0,exp(-b*t), t>0,0);
>
> a:=1; #this can be anything you want
>
> animate(plot,[f(x),x=-5..5,y=0..100],b=0..5,frames=100); #play with the values of b and the number of frames

Comment: If `a` and `b` are not yet assigned values then another way to investigate the behaviour is with, say, plots:-interactiveparams(plot,
                         [piecewise(t=0,a,t<0,exp(-b*t), t>0,0),
                          t=-2..2,view=0..6,discont=true,
                          thickness=2],
                         a=0.0..2.0,b=-10.0..2.0);

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this one, feel free to add it to and answer of your own if you want, or I can edit mine to include it

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done unless you give Maple the values $a$ and $b$. If we know these values then you can put them in the following command:

> $f:=t->\text{piecewise}(t=0,a,t<0,\text{exp}(-b*t),0<t,0)$;
>
> $\text{plot}(f(t),t=t_1..t_2);$

wherein $t_1$ and $t_2$ are some constats.

Comment: It should be f:=t-> in your definition

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Oh! Thanks. I see you attempt to plot his function by employing **animate** command. Great one! :)